# Is there a way to add an identity to Amazon SES through a form in Javascript?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, firebase, amazon-ses

I have a form in my React app that signs up users in Firebase. Can I also use said form to add those email addresses to this SES screen?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need add your application users as verified *senders*?

Comment: I don’t think so. I only need to add them as verified receivers.

Comment: In that case, you are trying to solve the wrong problem.  You don't need to verify receivers.  You need to request production access.   https://stackoverflow.com/a/35947500/1695906  Verifying receivers is only for testing, and only needed while you are sandboxed.

Comment: That is great, thanks!

Comment: I have closed this question as a duplicate of another question that asks the question you were unknowingly looking for the answer to... because even though it is technically possible (albeit indirectly) to do what was asked here, it would be the wrong solution to the problem, it could make a mess of things, and you would run into other issues sooner or later if you tried to use SES in your production environment while still sandboxed.  If there are others in the community who disagree with the closure of the question, I welcome their input.